# python: scraping with button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I faced the problem when I try to collect all the comments from https://ideas.lego.com/projects/6f1d4d6e-f47a-467a-8b10-d918d04e6d5c/comments_tab, there is two types of button for comments

1. Load more comments, I solve it
2. Show the reply, that one I couldn't solve it.

i tred to add it as button and click it but not work fine

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time


    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get('https://ideas.lego.com/projects/6f1d4d6e-f47a-467a-8b10-d918d04e6d5c/comments_tab')

    sbtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("load-more")
    sbtn.click()

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height


    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    z = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'comment-message cms'})
    #print(z)
    print(len(z))
```

Thanks

====== Edits ======

what i did :
Load all the page with scrolling all down the page and collect all the comments, except the under the reply, because I didn't find a way to click the button to complete load all of them

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck? What are the exact _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_? Update the question with the error you are seeing.